# How to use QT and Python to convert project in Visual Studio

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, qt

I have to work on an open source project, and right now I don't have any experience with QT and Python. In the Github page of that project they have mentioned steps to convert the project to Visual Studio project.

I installed Qt, Visual Studio 2017, also set environment variables.

But when I try to use Python command in CMD/PowerShell, it is not working.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Here is an extract of the instructions to follow :

Link : https://github.com/BelledonneCommunications/linphone-desktop

[image]

Comment: So you are saying python is not in your path? If so, I bet you know how to fix that.

Comment: I have set  PATH="C:\Qt\5.9\msvc2015\bin;%PATH%" in my environment variable

Comment: you must post the error you get on step3, because it's not recognizing is too vague

Comment: @Melebius Edited my post with link to the instruction.